# Gitlab 12.X - Get project id from storage path in a pre-receive hook

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

With legacy storage, when a pre-receive hook fires, it is easy to guess the URL of the repository involved as the path is "group/project-name.git".

With new hashed storage in Gitlab, the "pwd" command will return a path such as d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35.git  if the project id is 2.

=> How can I get the project id based on the hashed path ?

My aim is to check that all the commits being pushed by someone are authored by people who are actually authorized to write inside that project. I cannot do so if I do not know which project is involved. Although I can launch the "gitlab-rails console"  and used "ProjectRepository.find_by", it is not practical to use that script in the context of a hook.

There are Push Rules that allows to do that. However, Push Rules are not free and are not available in Gitlab CE.

Also, from an admin point of view, it is important to be able to find quickly the project id of a repository based on its repository storage path without necessarily having to launch the "gitlab-rails console".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an environment variable available to the `pre-receive` hook - `GL_REPOSITORY` which will have a value like `project-123`. This is the project ID.

Comment: It looks like this environmental variable is also available in post-receive hook but I get empty value it if it do an "echo "$GL_REPOSITORY" in the <project_hash>.git  path? Does this only give out the value once the commit is made?