# How to get group and repository name in server-side Gitlab global hooks starting with 13.1

Tags: git, gitlab, hook

My organization uses Gitlab CE and server-side git hooks. Specifically we use global pre-recieve hooks to validate commit messages (the one placed in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/pre-receive.d`). Validation rules are different for different Gitlab groups, so the script parses the full path to the repository and based on the group applies different rules.

We used to get the full path to the repository, including group, using `PWD` environmental variable in the past. But it looks like starting with Gitlab **13.1** this variable is no longer available. Also since new repositories are created in @hashed folder this approach anyway needs to be adjusted.

We've tried to use `git config --get gitlab.fullpath` in the pre-recieve hook and so far it works fine for all repositories except wiki repositories (like `<project_name>.wiki.git`). Also it's not a documented approach, so it might break again in the future. Is there any official way of getting the group name in pre-recieve hook?

UPD: it looks like there is a workaround using gitlab-rails, but it's far from optimal:

1. `GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` environment variable contains the path like `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/dd/8e/dd8e8c8c9dae8978f122d7bcf3d0d49f6a0e86b9fc35528f55e78f7408927bb1.git/objects/incoming-16WBe9` which is a directory inside the repo directory
2. Extract the repo hash from the path above and use the following command to lookup the full path: `gitlab-rails runner "puts ProjectRepository.find_by(disk_path: '@hashed/dd/8e/dd8e8c8c9dae8978f122d7bcf3d0d49f6a0e86b9fc35528f55e78f7408927bb1').project.full_path"`

But the issue with this approach is that `GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` might get changed in future and that `gitlab_rails` command takes ~30 seconds to execute on our installation, which is unacceptably long

UPD2: there is `GL_REPOSITORY` environment variable with the project `ID`, that can be used to find out the full path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399790/13881221

UPD3 2020-07-07: there is `GL_PROJECT_PATH` environment variable included starting with Gitlab **13.1.3** that resolves the issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/merge_requests/2313

Answer (score 0):

Actually GL_PROJECT_PATH has this format:
`group/subgroup/repo_name`
You can customize update hook on git server and from there, use group or subgroup.
For example, you can use regex to get group name like this:
`cut -d'/' -f1 <<< $GL_PROJECT_PATH`
more information about git hooks: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks